# Is there an easy solution to show Yes and No in a silverlight combobox and bind to database?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, combobox

I have a bit defined in my database 0=no, 1=yes.  I have a silverlight combo with the values "Yes" and "No" in it.  How can I bind my bit value to the combo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't state what data access machinary you are using but the typical tools will expose a bit field as a boolean property.  The easiest approach would be to use a value converter.

Here is the basic idea (might need some more defensive coding):-

```
public class BoolToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public String FalseString { get; set; }
    public String TrueString { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return FalseString;
        else
            return (bool)value ? TrueString : FalseString;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Equals(TrueString);
    }
}
```

With that in your application you can now add it to a `Resources` property (typically the App.xaml)

```
<Resources>
   <local:BoolToStringConverter x:Key="CvtYesNo" FalseString="No" TrueString="Yes" />
</Resources>
```

Now you would create your combobox like this:-

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding YourBitField, Converter={StaticResource CvtYesNo}, Mode=TwoWay}">
   <sys:String>Yes<sys:String>
   <sys:String>No<sys:String>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: I'm using Silverlight 3 with Linq2Sql.  Thanks for the input.  Let me dig into that.

Comment: For the above code to work include the namespace...xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib". Also, FYI if you're copying the above code the last ComboBox tag is misspelled.

Comment: @DeveloperDan:  What about the local: alias?